# HTML form has no action string?

Tags: java, html, apache, networking, post

I want to write an application with java to send POST method to a URL . The problem is that there is no action string . I wrote the java code below to programmatically sign in to the site but it does not work . Any information can help .

This is the form and validation:

```html
<form method="post" action="" name="login_form" id="login_form" onSubmit="return ValidateForm();">

    <input type="text" name="email" id="login_email" value="" class="txt" /></td>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="login_password" value="" class="txt" /></td>

    <select name="lang" id="lang">
        <option value="en" label="English" selected="selected">English</option>
        <option value="Fr" label="French">French</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

</form>
```

```js
function ValidateForm(){
    var emailID=document.login_form.email
    var ps=document.login_form.password

    if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
        alert("Please enter email address");
        emailID.focus();
        return false
    }

    if (ps.value==''){
        ps.focus();
        alert("Please enter password");
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

This is my client application which uses org.apache.http  and is written in java :

```
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://something.com/");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "myemail@yahoo.com"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "blahblahblah"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", "en"));

hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps,Consts.UTF_8));
Myresponse = Myhttpclient.execute(hpost,MyHttpContext);
```

Comment: `action=""` ---> form action i guess !!!

Comment: The `action` attribute is not mandatory. If it isn't there, the form will post to the URL it is on.

Comment: yes a link to send data to . for example action="ee.html" .

Comment: "Not working" is a very poor description of your problem. What isn't working? Isn't it posting? Is the form not submitting? Do you not get the correct form values? Does your computer blow up?

Comment: I mean it sends data to but the server dose not send me back any html .

Comment: Thanks J.Steen . You really help me . The server sends me back 302 code an I can log in now. 
Thanks so much dear